# Error parsing date Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I had saved date in server database as timestamp.

Then I am converting timestamp to date using below code

```
completeDate : new Date(timestamp);


It shows date : Wed Feb 28 2018 00:35:06 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

But When i try to set in ion-datetime. it throws error

```
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="history.completeDate"></ion-datetime>
```

**Error parsing date: "Wed Feb 28 2018 00:35:06 GMT+0530 (IST)". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime**

can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 3):

Like  [@Animator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124437/animator) said you need an ISO 8601 datetime format.

So you must to define your type as string and set your value as:

```
completeDate : (new Date(timestamp)).toISOString();
```

More information on [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 2):

When I looked into the documentation this is what I found:

> Ionic uses the ISO 8601 datetime format for its value. The value is simply a string, rather than using JavaScript's Date object. Additionally, when using the ISO datetime format, it makes it easier to serialize and pass within JSON objects, and sending databases a standardized format which it can be easily parsed if need be.

Also ISO 8601 datetime format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ
```

Javascript date object can convert many string formats but this specific component requires an ISO 8601 formatted string, so you need to make further conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to manually create the ISO string from the given date format - in my case :(dd-MMM-yyyy)

```
function xx_formatDate(p_date){
                //to resolve error - "Please provide valid ISO 8601 string."
                if(p_date){
                    let formattedDate = new Date(p_date);
                    let dateArr = formattedDate.toLocaleDateString().split('/');
                    let l_year = dateArr[2];
                    let l_month = dateArr[0];
                    let l_date = dateArr[1];
                    l_month = (l_month.length>1)? l_month : '0'+l_month;
                    l_date = (l_date.length>1)? l_date : '0'+l_date;

                    return l_year+'-'+l_month+'-'+l_date;
                } else {
                    return ;
                }
            }
```